# Ajax post model parameter changed between view and controller

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I can't figure out the reason for this error:

1. I create an `ajax.post` using a parameter from my view model.

   var url = '@Url.Action("RemoveParticipants","Campaign")';
   var id = @Html.Raw(Model.CampaignId);
   var model = { cid: id, ids: ids, removeAll: removeAll};
2. My view source shows that my parameters are correct.

   var url = '/Campaign/RemoveParticipants';
   var id = 575241000000002017;
   var model = { cid: id, ids: ids, removeAll: removeAll};
3. The request hits normally the controller, but the id has "magically" changed to "575241000000002050":

[image: Debugging screenshot]

I am out of ideas on how to fix this!

Comment: Will you include your full view and your controller action code, it would help better.

Comment: The cid in your controller is string, so it would be better to treat that as a string in your client side model too.

Comment: You found the problem @Thangadurai :) By changing the id to string " " the action works as expected!

Answer (score 0):

As @Thangadurai commented, I was not posting the id as string. By adding ' ' to my javascript id variable `var id = '@Html.Raw(Model.CampaignId)';` the action works as expected.